# How to create an auto-renewing subscription for an in-app purchase to be accepted by Apple?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store

I have a problem with submitting my app to the apple store. It seems that they don't want I create an auto-renewing subscription for an in-app purchase. They want me to create a non-consumable in-app purchase product type. Here is the entire message:

**Answer from Apple:**

*Thank you for your resubmission. Upon further review, we found that the following issue persists:

Guideline 3.1.2 - Business - Payments - Subscriptions

Your in-app purchase is currently flagged as auto-renewing subscription. However, it would be more appropriate to use the non-consumable in-app purchase product type because the product is used to unlock features of the app. Non-consumable products are only purchased once by users and are always available on all devices that are associated with that user's iTunes account. Auto-renewing subscriptions are intended for periodical apps, such as magazines and newspapers.

Next Steps

The product type cannot be changed once an in-app purchase product has been created. Therefore, you will need to create a new in-app purchase product with the correct product type.

To create new in-app purchases:

- Log in to iTunes Connect

- Click on "My Apps"

- Select your app

- Click on "Features" to create new in-app purchases

- Click Save

- Once you've completed all changes, click the "Submit for Review" button at the top of the App Version Information page.

The current products will show as "Rejected" in iTunes Connect.

Resources

Learn more about how to offer in-app purchases in iTunes Connect Developer Help.

Note: Apps that offer in-app purchase products that must be restorable are required to include a "Restore" feature. The following in-app purchase types must be restorable:

- non-consumable products

- auto-renewing subscriptions

- free subscriptions

For more information, please see the Restoring Purchased Products section of the In-App Purchase Programming Guide.*

I don't understand, because they say that *Auto-renewing subscriptions are intended for periodical apps, such as magazines and newspapers.*, but Deezer, Spotify, NetFlix, LinkedIn, etc... are not magazines and newspapers and they are auto-renewing subscription.

May be my code is not correct for this type of Subscription? If it is the case, here is my code:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions{
    for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions){
        //if you have multiple in app purchases in your app,
        //you can get the product identifier of this transaction
        //by using transaction.payment.productIdentifier
        //
        //then, check the identifier against the product IDs
        //that you have defined to check which product the user
        //just purchased

        switch(transaction.transactionState){
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing: NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Purchasing");
                //called when the user is in the process of purchasing, do not add any of your own code here.
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                //this is called when the user has successfully purchased the package (Cha-Ching!)
                [self doMonthlySubscription]; //you can add your code for what you want to happen when the user buys the purchase here, for this tutorial we use Monthly Subscription
                [self viewDidAppear:NO];
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Purchased");
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Restored");
                //add the same code as you did from SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased here
                [self doMonthlySubscription]; //you can add your code for what you want to happen when the user buys the purchase here, for this tutorial we use Monthly Subscription
                [self viewDidAppear:NO];
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                //called when the transaction does not finish
                if(transaction.error.code == SKErrorPaymentCancelled){
                    NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Cancelled");
                    //the user cancelled the payment ;(
                }
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred:
                NSLog(@"Deferred");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
 - (void)doMonthlySubscription{
        [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        isMonthlySubscription = YES;
        //set the bool for whether or not they purchased it to YES, you could use your own boolean here, but you would have to declare it in your .h file

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:isMonthlySubscription forKey:@"isMonthlySubscription"];
        //use NSUserDefaults so that you can load wether or not they bought it
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
```

I really don't understand what is the problem?

(I am goin' to have them at phone, I will update if more informations)

Comment: It sounds like Apple doesn't think that the feature that you are providing via subscription warrants a recurring payment; rather it should be unlocked for a one-off payment.

Comment: @Paulw11 They said that "Auto-renewing subscriptions are intended for periodical apps, such as magazines and newspapers", but I don't undertand because Deezer, Spotify, NetFlix, LinkedIn, etc... works like this and they are not magazines and newspapers. So you think my code is good ?

Comment: They are saying that the feature you are offering via subscription is not suitable for a subscription model. It is nothing to do with your code. Apps can definitely provide non-content subscriptions. I have apps myself that use subscriptions for higher tiers of service. Unfortunately no one here can help you.  You need to resolve this with Apple.

Comment: @Paulw11 mmm ok thank you very much for your answer. I will speak to them.

Comment: @Paulw11 A last question. Do your auto-renewable applications offers new capabilities that allow you to create that auto-renewable in-app purchase? May be to subscribe to that auto-renewable, needs to offer to the customers some "new features" etc... usually ?

Comment: My apps allow you to use more of the features that are included; for example, to print to more printers as well as have more functionality, such as integrating with Active Directory.